# Difference between import pdb at the beginning and import pdb; pdb.set_trace()

Tags: python, python-import, pdb

I usually put the line

```py
import pdb
```

on top of my program code, along with other imports. For debugging, I then only have to type `pdb.set_trace()` in the spot where I want the program to halt. The initial import stays where it is even after finishing my work on the program.

I have seen other people just adding the line

```py
import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
```

where they want the program to halt, getting around the initial `import pdb`.

Do the two approaches differ in any way? Is it preferred to use the second approach, so that no unwanted `import pdb` stays in my final code, causing an unwanted and unnecessary import everytime someone uses it?

Comment: There is no difference except for if you only need to import it given a condition. The one-liner version is just more convenient because it's unnecessary to add `import pdb` on top while you're going to remove it later anyway.

Comment: @sK500 Am I going to remove it later anyway? …

Comment: `pdb.set_trace()` is for pausing execution at a certain line for debugging purposes if that's what you intended to do. If you're using python3.7 or later versions, you can use [breakpoint()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#breakpoint) instead.

Comment: Just use a modern version of python and `breakpoint()` (no import statement required)

Comment: It's good practice to only import packages that you use. You will want to remove the import statement if you are not using `pdb.set_trace()` hence both on the same line has its benefits

Comment: A remark: It seems that `breakpoint()` does not work with modules that I have imported in a Jupyter notebook. (This is not a follow-up question, just found it interesting.)

Answer (score 1):

Is it preferred to use the second approach?

In my opinion: Yes.

As you said, no need to include the pdb module in general.

Therefore `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()` is a convenient way to include it when debugging, so that easily can be removed when debugging is done. This is the way I always do it, and probably lots of other people do it like that too.